# javascript code for marquee using jquery1.3.2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I have situation where I have to display horizontal scrolling text and direction should be from left  without using marquee tag .And it should use only  jquery1.3.2.min.js plugin  .

pls help me. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery animate (http://api.jquery.com/animate/). Your element needs to be absolute positioned and you can animate the css left property.

Comment: I just tried but its not working ,because when text size increases it will also increase div size.

Comment: wrap your text with another div and animate that div's left instead.